# Exec /bin/bash in Docker Compose

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to automate a docker-compose file. I want to do some preliminary tasks like updating source codes, building a library, and automatically run `bash` terminal on the container just by calling `docker-compose up`. Is there a way to do this?
I tried to do the following:

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
  service1:
    ...
  service2:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.hardware
      context: .
    container_name: container2
    network_mode: "host"
    privileged: true
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY
      - MACHINE=${MACHINE}
    shm_size: 256M
    volumes:
      ...
    stop_signal: SIGINT
    working_dir: /home/user
    command: bash -c "./Arduino/libraries/build_arduino_lib.sh && exec /bin/bash"
```

But the process terminates without executing /bin/bash.

Comment: Are you sure of that? f/e, are you sure it doesn't execute bash, but then immediately exit because there's no stdin available?

Comment: (It'd be easier for us to test if the code you provided were a [mre], the shortest possible thing that could be run without changes to see the behavior ourselves; the `...`s -- like the other references to content not included in the question -- make that not the case).

Comment: Is there a way to check whether it exits immediately? I am not quite sure myself since I am not very familiar with this. And sorry, I cannot share the full code for several reasons.

Comment: So, one easy way is to change your last `bash -c` to `bash -xc`; that'll make bash log commands it's running to stderr, so if it runs you can see the two steps it takes (the first being running `build_arduino_lib.sh` and the second being `exec`ing the other copy of bash). And we don't _want_ the full code; the "minimal" part of [mre] is something we take seriously. Instead, we want the shortest possible code **that actually reproduces the problem**. See the "Tricks for Trimming" section of http://sscce.org/ for some pointers on how to get there.

Comment: "Tasks like updating source code and building a library" should generally be done in a Dockerfile; the main process for your container (the `CMD` in the Dockerfile) should actually run the job and not an interactive shell.  You also can't really launch an interactive shell from a `docker-compose.yml` file.  I'd suggest revisiting this overall approach.

Comment: @DavidMaze the updating and library building are done in the dockerfile. However, I need to run a setup for some hardware connection and then run another bash file from inside the container, that's why I tried to run bash. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the response. I understand, I will try to make a reprex for this question. After trying with ```bash -xc```, it turned out the ```exec``` command is executed, but exits right after. Is there a way to stop it from directly exiting?

Answer (score 2):

To get an interactive bash, you need to use `run` and specify a service :

```
docker-compose run service2
```