# How to get interactive user input to python script running in Docker container?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, interactive

I have a rudimentary python script named `my_python_script.py` that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def main():
   x = input('What is your name? ')
    print('x = {}'.format(x))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run it locally from my command line it performs exactly as you would expect.

However, now I'm trying to run this same script from within a Docker container. So I created a `Dockerfile` that looks like this:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: .
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: -c "./my_python_script.py"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

When I run it with `docker-compose up`, it fails like this:

```
Creating myservice_1 ... done
Attaching to myservice_1
myservice_1  | What is your name?  Traceback (most recent call last):
myservice_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/./my_python_script.py", line 7, in <module>
myservice_1  |     main()
myservice_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/./my_python_script.py", line 3, in main
myservice_1  |     x = input('What is your name? ')
myservice_1  | EOFError: EOF when reading a line
myservice_1 exited with code 1
```

How can I make this python script accept interactive input from my keyboard when it is running inside a Docker container?

Comment: I imagine you would need the `-it` flag when you start the container

Comment: -it for docker compose discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150040/3214422)

Comment: I added the following two lines to my `docker-compose.yml` which correspond to the `-it` flags: `stdin_open: true` and `tty: true`. When I did that, it simply sits there and waits instead of prompting the user for their name.

Comment: This is specifically about python - please reopen

Comment: @tripleee You used the wrong duplicate.

Comment: This is specifically about Docker, and the solution is the `-t` option, isn't it?

Comment: @tripleee yeah, but the container is started with `docker-compose`. This would be a more appropriate dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249744/interactive-shell-using-docker-compose/39150040#39150040

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108486/exec-bin-bash-in-docker-compose) you might want to try:

```
docker-compose run myservice
```

I am no docker expert, but I think that `docker-compose up` will simply start all services from `docker-compose.yaml` and then output the log of all services.

See also this part of the `docker-compose` [FAQ](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-up-run-and-start).

Comment: The question is how to make one of those services read input from standard input.

Comment: Thank you. But isn't the question is how to run the shown script from within a docker container? I believe, if so, this is an appropriate approach. Also, simply adding the `stdin_open: true` and `tty: true` parameters didn't work for me and seems to not work for the OP as well. See also the upvoted comment on the answer of the duplicate you marked.

Comment: It doesn't read from standard input for me.

Comment: This is what I am referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36265910/12661819

Comment: Indeed, like it says, that doesn't give you a proper interactive session, unless you resort to separately running one with `docker exec -it`.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost here. It says you can *also* do that, as another option. If I run `docker-compose run myservice` like above on my Ubuntu 20.04, I get the output `What is your name?` and then `x = Dominik` after I entered my name. Whereas `docker-compose up` even with said parameters gives me a blank and no input option. But maybe I am just misunderstanding something.

Comment: Also the linked docker-compose FAQ states "The run command acts like docker run -ti in that it opens an interactive terminal to the container [...]."

Comment: When I tried this, I got `docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myservice, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.`. If I don't use docker compose, it won't use my `docker-compose.yml` file, so it will have no clue what `myservice` is.

Comment: Did you accidentially use `docker run myservice`? If so, please try `docker-compose run myservice` like above.